# No disc space while installing SDK components in android studio

Tags: android-studio, sdk, android-sdk-manager

I am trying to install necessary SDK Components in Android Studio. I have 355 GB free space on my D drive, and 200 mb on C drive. Android Studio, SDK Location, tmp, temp are all on D. However when I am trying to install  those SDK components I get an error which says, there is not enough space on my drive.

```
Preparing "Install Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image (revision: 8)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/x86-26_r08.zip
An error occurred while preparing SDK package Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image: No space left on disc.
```

Comment: You have installed Android Studio on C Drive (default)

Comment: It looks like the temporary file to be unzipped are downloaded in C: nevertheless. If that's the case, I guess the only option you have is to make some free space there. Be sure you are installing AS on D: though :-P

Comment: Android Studio is for sure installed on D.

Comment: Ok, it looks like temporary files to be unzipped are downloaded in C as you said so I did some cleaning on C and it works fine now :)